# case when null then empty in oracle insert statement

Tags: oracle, triggers, sql-insert, isnull, is-empty

I am writing trigger in which i have to insert value into `track` table if value changes in `parent_key` table. I have to check if the value is null then set it to empty else the old value and same thing i have to do for new value. I tried the below case statement but its not inserting into track table if the initial old/new value is null.

```
create or replace TRIGGER parent_key_trg AFTER UPDATE ON parent_key
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF NOT  :old.track_name=:new.track_name THEN
    INSERT INTO track  (TRACK_OLD_VALUE,TRACK_NEW_VALUE)
    VALUES (case when :old.track_name is null then '' else to_char(:old.track_name) end,case when :new.track_name is null then '' else to_char(:new.track_name) end);
  END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In oracle, an empty string `''` is exactly the same as `null`.

You could change your `IF` to the following:

```
IF Nvl(:old.track_name, 'NULL') <> Nvl(:new.track_name, 'NULL') THEN
```

Since you cannot compare `null = null`

Comment: but why do i need to change in IF statement ? Because in if statement  i have to check only old value not equaly to new value then it will go in the case when statement

Comment: I have explained it further. Basically, you cannot compare `NULL = NULL`, you can do `NULL IS NULL` or `'literal' = 'literal'`, but not `NULL = 'literal'` or `NULL = NULL`. Look up null comparisons in SQL,

Answer (score 1):

the comparison of both `null = null`  and `not (null = null)`  results false as you can see by this statement

```
select case
         when null = null then
          'eq'
         when not (null = null) then
          'not eq'
         else
          '?'
       end
  from dual;
--> '?'
```

therefore you should compare `null` values by `is` operator, in your case

```
IF :old.track_name <> :new.track_name 
 OR :old.track_name is null and :new.track_name is not null 
 OR :old.track_name is not null and :new.track_name is null THEN
```

the case statement `case when :old.track_name is null then '' else to_char(:old.track_name) end` is unnecessary, because `null` and `''` is the same. What do you want to insert in case of `null` value?